# Spring security jwt error The parsed JWT indicates it was signed with the 'RS256' signature algorithm

Tags: java, spring, jwt

During jwt token checking I receive this error:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: The parsed JWT indicates it was signed with the 'RS256' signature algorithm, but the provided javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec key may not be used to verify RS256 signatures.  Because the specified key reflects a specific and expected algorithm, and the JWT does not reflect this algorithm, it is likely that the JWT was not expected and therefore should not be trusted.  Another possibility is that the parser was provided the incorrect signature verification key, but this cannot be assumed for security reasons.  at
 io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:393)
 ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar:0.11.5]     at
 io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:529)
 ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar:0.11.5]     at
 io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:589)
 ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar:0.11.5]     at
 io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
 ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar:0.11.5]     at
 techpoc.authenticationsample.service.JwtService.extractAllClaims(JwtService.java:58)
 ~[classes/:na]
```

The token is generated with the below code

```
public class JwtService {
    
    public static final String SECRET = "5367566B59703373367639792F423F4528482B4D6251655468576D5A71347437";
    public String generateToken(String userName) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userName);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String userName) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 30))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }

    private Key getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes= Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this mistake?

thanks

Comment: Well the message is pretty clear. It expects `RS256` and you are using `HS256` which are different. So either your signing is wrong or your validation is wrong (judging from the message I suspect the validation part, which isn't part of the question).

Comment: Correct suggestions, but problem is that I don t want to use an RS algortith, the idea is to use an HS256 with the key SECRET. How can modified the application? Thanks

Comment: Then modify the validation, you cannot change one side of the implementation. You cannot just decide well lets sign differently without changing the validation side of things.